# Groupby date and process by a given time interval using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series

I have a large dataframe containing several months' data and I need to process data between [09:00:00-11:59:59] for each of the 31 days.

The structure of the dataframe (df) looks as below:

```
id,date,value
5,2012-03-01 00:00:00,0
2,2012-03-01 00:00:00,0
3,2012-03-01 00:00:00,0
1,2012-03-01 00:00:00,0
4,2012-03-01 00:00:00,0
```

I can easily filter the dataframe for times between [09:00:00 - 11:59:59] using:

```
indx = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])
df1 = df.iloc[indx.indexer_between_time('09:00:00','11:59:59')]
```

And I can also group each day's dataframe using:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df_grouped = df.groupby([df['date'].dt.date])
df_list = []
for idx, data in df_grouped:
    df_list.append(data)
```

How can I tie this together to get a list of dataframes containing only data between [09:00:00-11:59:59]. The intention is to loop through the dataframes with data for [09:00:00-11:59:59] and pass each of them into some function for further processing:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have `df1`, now groupby on that:

```
df_grouped = df1.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df1['date']).dt.date) )
df_list = [d for _,d in df_grouped]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but how can I pass each of these df_list items into a function as separate dataframes for further processing.

Comment: Each item in `df_list` is a dataframe, you can just pass it to your function `for d in df_list: func(d)` However, there is a catch that these are slices of the original `df`, so you don't want to modify them.